# Не видит properties файл.Android

Tags: java, android

Никак не могу понять почему студия не видит файл. Уже куда только его не пихал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В пути файла оставьте только "res/mail.properties"

Comment: Нет, не работает, уже пробывал. Сейчас перепроверил

Comment: Файлы, брошенные куда попало, не попадают в готовое приложение - их нужно размещать в специальных папках. Если это код только для Андроида, а не универсальный Java/Android - используйте ассеты. Урок с примерами: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/assets.php

Answer (score 0):

Когда JVM компилирует код, у нее изменяется структура, поэтому , если мы положим properties файл "куда попало", то после компиляции ссылка на данный файл будет не действительна ( по данной ссылке не будет файла). Для данных файлов есть папка ресурсов. Если в обычной Java это папка resourse, то в Android проекте нам самим нужно создавать папку assets. По структуре она находится в самом проекте рядом с папкой res. После чего необходимо реализовать AssetsManadger, указав на данную папку.Уже после с помощью asset.open() открыть нужный файл. Про Assets и про File можно найти в интернете.
Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Технически можно и как в обычной Java - создать папку `resources` (`/Проект/модуль/src/main/resources`) и читать оттуда через `getResourceAsStream()`, с оговоркой, что путь нужно указывать относительно этой папки, так же как при сборке и запуске JAR.